# Project Euler number 35

Tags: c#

Using the following code I am able to find the circular primes but there are some unexpected values. e.g. if '13' is a circular prime then '31' should be eliminated. Please suggest a way to eliminate such occurrences.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PrimeNumberAlgorithm
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch sw = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
            int n = 100;
            int check_limit = (Int32)Math.Sqrt(Convert.ToDouble(n));
            int count_Circular = 0;

            bool[] b_arr = new bool[n - 2];

            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < b_arr.Length; i++)
            {
                b_arr[i] = true;
            }
            int currentNum = 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < check_limit; i++)
            {
                if (b_arr[i] == true)
                {
                    for (int j =i+currentNum;j < b_arr.Length; j += currentNum)
                    {
                        b_arr[j] = false;
                    }
                }
                currentNum++;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < n-2; i++)
            {
                if (b_arr[i])
                {
                    int j = i + 2;
                    if (j != 2 && j != 5)
                    {
                        string numStr = j.ToString();
                        char[] chr_numStr = numStr.ToCharArray();

                        for (int k = 0; k < chr_numStr.Length; k++)
                        {
                            if (chr_numStr[k] % 2 == 0 || chr_numStr[k] == 5)
                            {
                                b_arr[i] = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }

                if (b_arr[i])
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("The circular primes are:\n");
                    Console.WriteLine(i+2);
                    count_Circular++;
                }

            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("The total number of circular primes:{0}",count_Circular);
            Console.WriteLine("The time taken:{0} sec",sw.ElapsedMilliseconds/(1000));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have assumed n=100 but in actual question it is 1000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood the question.  Read it again:

- "There are thirteen such primes below 100: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, **13**, 17,
  **31**, 37, 71, 73, 79, and 97"

A hint: If the number contains any of the digits 0, 2, 4, 5, 6, 8 then it cannot be circular, unless it is 2 or 5.